# Sql query to update table based on other tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table structre like this:

Table `MainTable`

Columns:

```
Id INT, 
TableName Varchar(50),
StartValue VARCHAR(50)
```

Here TableName column have names of all the tables present in the database

Now I need to update "StartValue" column in `MainTable` from corresponding tables. Any idea how to achieve this?

Example

`MainTable`

```
Id TableName StartValue
----------------------
1  table1      NULL  
2  Table2     Null
```

I need to update `StartValue` column of `MainTable` by getting top 1 value from table name present in the tables

Means record 1 will get first value from table1 and record 2 will get first value from table2

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
use DBName
go

declare cur cursor for 
select Table_Name from MainTable

declare @var varchar(100)
open cur
fetch next from cur into @var
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'update MT set Start_Value = t.Start_Value from MainTable MT cross join ' + @var +' t where MT.Table_Name = ''' + @var +''''
exec sp_executesql @sql
fetch next from cur into @var

end
close cur
deallocate cur

--select * from MainTable
```

HTH!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating a column based on the value in another column, you could use DynamicSQL to build and then execute the query (probably using a CURSOR to loop through the rows of MainTable

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLENAME FROM MAINTABLE 
OPEN cur1
FETCH NEXT FROM cur1INTO @TABLENAMEWHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
SET @DYNSQL = 'UPDATE MAINTABLE SET STARTVALUE = SELECT TOP 1 STARTVALUE FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE                              
EXEC sp_executesql @DYNSQL
```

This is just one approach. Caveat regarding the use of cursors and DynamicSQL as always applies

Comment: Of course, scalar subqueries should be enclosed in parentheses.